# How can I make ajax safe?

Tags: php, ajax

I have an ajax for save address. I have some parameters like username, Address, Location. Now user can see all parameters and is not safe.

ajax code:

```
$.ajax({ 
        url: 'inc/saveAddress.php',
        data: {"username": window.username,
               "name": name,
               "address": address,
               "lat": window.lats,
               "lng": window.lngs,
               },
        type: 'post',
        success: function(result)
        {
            window.location.replace('https://example.com');
        }
    });
```

How can I check this requst is from what address by `PHP`? or anything to safe that.

Comment: I cant find similar questions.. please give me link if exist..

Comment: Nothing on the client side can really be considered safe from the user. A user with enough determination will find a way around any measures you take.

Comment: @Carcigenicate so ajax is not safe and I should change my way.. Right?

Comment: Everything done on the client end can be snooped by the user. This isn't specific to Ajax.

Comment: making ajax safe is not different from non-ajax forms! you should validate your data on the server side.

Comment: @Carcigenicate But should be a way in php to limit this..

Comment: @HadiAghandeh yes I need a way to check this request is from my site or not!

Comment: you need csrf protection. there are some tutorials on the internet on how to implement csrf protection in php.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is to create and send a unique key which can know only the server. If key is wrong send an error back.

Comment: how is that going to help OP ?  maybe a comment, but certainly not an answer.

Comment: it helps OP to make it safe. Ok, safer as before. Thatswhy its my answer. btw, user with less then 50 reputations cant comment. ;) and as long users as u disvote my answers so i cant comment for a long time.